# Is this off-topic if poster already decided the answer?

Tags: discussion

Concerning this SU post: [Unable to use internet due to suspected DNS malware](https://superuser.com/questions/786421/unable-to-use-internet-due-to-suspected-dns-malware)

It looks like original poster decided malware infection is to blame instead of any other possibilities, and is looking for malware removal tool and rejecting any other answers or inquiries. In such case, does the question become shopping question and off-topic for SU?

Answer (score 3):

A question like that isn't generally off-topic, it's just a bad question.

If the author already decided what the solution to their problem must be, than they exclude possible better solutions. Questions like that are also known as [XY problem questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The author should be made aware of what they're doing wrong and should be encouraged to edit their question. If they refuse to do that, a downvote is in order.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking is another option, since there's no evidence in the post that suggest a malware.

Answer (score 1):

If they are changing the question completely, I'd say they haven't narrowed it down, and it should be rolled back to the previous question so the current answers work. Changing the meaning completely means that there is another issue altogether, and should have its own question asked.

Comment: It's not in the edit, but in various comments -- OP made the intention very clear. He even opened a +100 bounty specially to tell others to help him remove malware and don't bother DNS settings.

Comment: Ahhh... I'm not sure in that case then